# around its central point

Tags: javascript, p5.js

My problem is as follows. I would like to rotate the grid around its central point but so far i can rotate it around the central point of the canvas. I've tried various settings but none of them brings the desired result. So far, I only manage to spin the grid around the central point of the canvas and its not what i was looking for. Please help. I am beginner 
 in p5js so any feedback will be apreceated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rotate an image around a pivot you've to:

- "move" the pivot to the origin (0, 0).
  That means you've to translate by `(-width / 2, -height / 2)`
- rotate the image
- "move" the pivot back to its original place.
  That means you've to translate by `(width / 2, height / 2)`

Since operations like [`translate`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/translate) and [`rotate`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/rotate), define a matrix and multiply the current matrix by the new matrix, this operations have to be performed in reverse order:

```js
push();

translate(width / 2, height / 2);
rotate(PI / 180 * 45);
translate(-width / 2, -height / 2);

imageMode(CENTER);
rectMode(CENTER);
layerOne.grid.display();
pop();
```